# CORS in Restfull Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache

I am trying to call RESTfull services on my localhost with a header information, its return CORS error. If call RESTfull service without header information, its return successfully result.  I am using AngularJS v1.2.15.

Answer (score 0):

you really need to add more info. Is your backend MVC, WEB API, or are you accessing an external API? What headers are you sending? We cant read minds so you need to tell us stuff...

Comment: Apache CXF, No external API, `$scope.auth = ('Basic ' + btoa($scope.username + ':' + $scope.password));
  $scope.res = $scope.repository;
  
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = $scope.auth;
     $http.defaults.headers.common['repository']= $scope.res;`